# how to create a vector as an argument

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, arguments, initializer-list

I have an object that takes a vector as one of it's constructor arguments. I will have around 1000 of these objects (contained in a vector) in each of 12 files by the time I'm finished, and I've been experimenting with layout. The best way I can find to work it is to create all arguments within the object definition.

Here is a basic version of the struct:

```
struct MyObject {
  MyObject (vector<int>);
  vector<int> paraList;
}
```

So my object definition will look something like this:

```
MyObject object1 ( {0, 1, 2} );
MyObject object2 ( {0, 3, 1} );
MyObject object3 ( {5, 7, 5, 6} );
MyObject object4 ( {4} );
```

This works, but what I'd really like to do is construct the objects within the vector definitions instead. Like so:

```
vector<MyObject> objectList {
  ( {0, 1, 2} ), 
  ( {0, 3, 1} ),
  ( {5, 7, 5, 6} ),
  ( {4} )  
};
```

It feels like that should work, but it doesn't. I get:

> ```
> error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
> error: expected ')' before '{' token
> error: expected '}' before ')' token
> ```

I feel like my syntax would be correct if this were possible, so is what I'm trying to do not possible?

EDIT:

Sorry, besides a few spelling mistakes I'm not sure why this is off topic. I've been reading through the rules and I'm still not sure, could you please comment or PM me what I've done wrong so I can avoid it in future? That's not meant to be moany, just want to make sure I get it right.

Comment: Remove the round parentheses.

Comment: You son of a gun! Of all the things I've tried, and after all that googling. Thank you very much, feel free to add that as an answer so I can tick it :D

Comment: Hmm, it now has a problem with the final  };  at the end of the list. Any ideas on that?

Comment: To explain, problems caused by typographical errors are off topic. You had an open bracket you shouldn't have, that was all the issue was. Since typos are unlikely to help future users as they are small problems, easily fixed and hyperspecific, they are considered off topic.

Comment: Ah, I think we have a misunderstanding. I didn't know how to do what I was asking above before, I just tried a few ideas that looked like they should work. I googled a fair bit, but struggled to find anything explaining this particular issue. Also, I was using the wrong brackets, simply removing a bracket didn't actually work in the end, I needed extra curly braces. So this isn't exactly a typo, but a lack of know-how.

Comment: I think this would help someone in the future if they were in my position, but I should probably delete my first comment in reply to my question, as I was mistaken in thinking that Kerrek had solved it (changing the first instance of MyObject construction made it look like he was right, but then a further error came up soon after when I applied it to all instances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
std::vector<MyObject> objectList {{{0, 1, 2}} , {{0, 3, 1}} , {{5, 7, 5, 6}} ,{{4}}};
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/53jj)

Comment: Ah! thank you, that's more like it. Cheers very much!